# Toggling standard output of a background process once already suppressed (unix)

Tags: java, unix, terminal, stdout

Currently I am running a program in the background from the command line that outputs to the terminal, however, I want to hide the output most of time time while I work.

`java -cp *:. MyJavaApp > /dev/null &`

Is there a way that I can make standard output show again once I bring the process to the foreground with `fg`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `screen` for that:

```
screen -d -m java -cp *:. MyJavaApp
```

When you want to see the output again, just reattach the screen (`screen -ls` will list the available screens, reattach with, for instance, `screen -D -RR`)

As a bonus, you have all the previous output available (up to the buffer limit defined by your configuration).

Or you can just use `screen`, issue your command in one window, have your shell in another, split horizontally, copy text from one window to the other and whatnot. A gold mine ;)

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of this command as I'm still fully getting to grips with the power of unix terminal since getting a Raspberry Pi.

Comment: The Unix terminal is an eternal source of discovery ;) Have fun!